# $6j$-symbol example in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, representation-theory

Can anyone provide me a simple context in quantum mechanics where the $6j$-symbol plays a role? I wish to understand the physical meaning of the $6j$-symbol so such a context will be helpful.

Comment: Which source did you use to find about the existence of "6j symbols"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a shame that most articles about $6j$-symbols (including
Wikipedia) fail to mention for what they are actually used.
They are used to transform between different
coupling schemes in systems with $3$ coupled angular momenta.

Quoted from [Introduction to the Graphical Theory of
Angular Momentum](https://beckassets.blob.core.windows.net/product/readingsample/9874588/9783642260605_excerpt_001.pdf) (chapter 2.2):

> If the theory of angular momentum is extended to consider
> more than two angular momenta one encounters several possible
> coupling schemes. For three angular momenta $j_1$, $j_2$ and $j_3$
> the coupling into a state of total angular momentum $J$ could
> proceed via two routes.
> As a first step one could couple $j_1$ and $j_2$ to $j_{12}$
> and then $j_{12}$ with $j_3$ to obtain the total $J$.
> Alternatively, one could first couple $j_2$ and $j_3$ to $j_{23}$
> and then $j_1$ with $j_{23}$ for $J$.
> The states belonging to the two coupling schemes can be
> transformed into each other and the elements of the
> transformation matrix are proportional to a 6j-symbol.
> A symbolic relation for these couplings is
> $$\left< [(j_1,j_2)j_{12},j_3]J \Big| [j_1,(j_2,j_3)j_{23}]J \right>
> \propto
> \begin{Bmatrix} j_3 & J & j_{12} \\ j_1 & j_2 & j_{23} \end{Bmatrix}
> $$

Comment: I think this is the best possible context that can be provided. I was expecting some three body problem in quantum mechanics where they would appear explicitly but I guess that is fine.